# Confused about transposes in kernel notation

Tags: self-study, svm, kernel-trick

I am studying machine learning and I ran into a challenge that does not make sense to me. Maybe it is a crazy or a simple question.

If we have kernel $ \phi_1(x)=[x, x^2]^T $ and $ \phi_2(x)=[2x, 2x^2]^T $ and if $ \phi_2$ has greater margin  than  $ \phi_1$, can we say it is true for $ \phi_1(x)=[x, x^2] $and $ \phi_2(x)=[2x, 2x^2]$? Can we remove the transpose signs ($^T$)?

Here is a screenshot of a problem to provide some context:

[image]

Comment: I've never seen this notation before. Can you provide references to the definition (I'm familiar with kernel methods, but not the notation used)?

Comment: @Barmaley.exe see my edits. okey now ?

Comment: What, in your opinion, is the difference between $[x, x^2]$ and $[x, x^2]^T$?

Comment: Also, what is $\phi_1[x, x^2]$ supposed to mean? Did you maybe mean $\phi_1(x) = [x, x^2]$? This is the notation used on the screenshot you posted as a reply to @Barmaley.exe.

Comment: please learn others instead of laugh :) is not different without T ? yes sorry. @amoeba

Comment: is it the same? would you please explain? @amoeba

Comment: I did not mean to laugh, @Houra, but it is important to know how much you already understand, in order to be able to provide a useful question. So I was trying to find out what your current understanding is. Do you know what the transpose it? Do you know what a vector is? Do you know a difference between $[1,2]$ and $[1,2]^T$?

Comment: @amoeba I means if the attached picture margin is greater so if we have $[x,x^2]$ and $[2x, 2x^2]$, again margin is greater. okey ?

Comment: I don't see how your comment answers my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a transpose doesn't really make sense. You define vectors as either rows or columns (based on the notation used here it appears column vectors are used) and then define the kernel/mapping function accordingly.

Basically, everything revolves around the following notation of inner product in feature space after using the mapping function $\phi(\cdot): \mathbb{R}^I \mapsto \mathbb{R}^F$ with $I$ and $F$ the input and feature space dimensionality, respectively (assuming column vectors):

$$\kappa(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}) = \langle \phi(\mathbf{u}), \phi(\mathbf{v}) \rangle = \phi(\mathbf{u})^T \phi(\mathbf{v}).$$

The reason the correct answer is A is evident, as all distances using $\phi_2$ will be a factor 4 larger than those of $\phi_1$. $\phi_2$ is essentially the same mapping as $\phi_1$, but scaling each mapped coordinate by a factor 2. If you have two (column) vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ and a feature-wise scaling factor $\alpha$, then:

$$\langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \rangle = \mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{v}$$
$$\langle \alpha \mathbf{u}, \alpha \mathbf{v} \rangle = \alpha^2 \mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{v} = \alpha^2 \langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \rangle$$

In the assignment $\phi_1(\mathbf{x}) = [\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}^2]^T$ and $\phi_2(\mathbf{x}) = [2\mathbf{x}, 2\mathbf{x}^2]^T = 2 \phi_1(\mathbf{x})$, which immediately means that all distances in the feature space induced by $\phi_2$ are a factor 4 larger than those in the space induced by $\phi_1$.

For the final notation you assume column vectors, but you might just as well use row vectors (then a dot product is $\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle=\mathbf{uv}^T$ instead of $\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle=\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{v}$). It's a matter of definition. However, if you start working in column vectors you have to continue doing so.

Comment: would you please explain a bit why in the attached picture, margin is greater ?

Comment: is it possible say more detail why " will be a factor 4 larger" ?

Comment: @HouraAsali does my extension clarify it for you?

Comment: yes so in whole factor 4, and on each coordinate factor 2?

Comment: @HouraAsali yes, since in the assignment $\phi_1(\mathbf{x}) = [\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}^2]^T$ and $\phi_2(\mathbf{x}) = [2\mathbf{x}, 2\mathbf{x}^2]^T = 2 \phi_1(\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: would you please add it to your answer?  I accept it. I think +100 bounty need a nicer answer :) that I sure set to you.

Comment: Thanks. Dear Mark please remove other comments, and my last request is can I get your email address?

Comment: You are wrong. the margin only extends in one direction. so not correct to say by factor 4.